# What happens if a BSOD happens while music is playing on a soundbar connected to BT?

Tags: windows, bsod

Will the soundbar play an odd sound effect and stay connected until the end of the BSOD or just disconnect immediately? Here's an example of an odd sound effect during a BSOD (on internal or wired speakers): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqIZMaXrl9Q But I don't know what would happen if the speakers were wireless.

Comment: Look in your dump folder and look at the dump with Nirsoft Blue Screen View. It is likely a driver that needs updating - probably blue tooth.

Comment: It won't fix the odd laughter effect in the linked video.

Comment: Is this an actual question you are facing, or a theoretical question? I'd imagine this will depend on the BT driver on the system, and the speakers.

Comment: You could use NotMyFault and test it for yourself. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/notmyfault.

Comment: @harrymc The odd sound effect is the tone when the system died.

Comment: I was just joking, but it's impossible to answer your question. You would just have to try, and there is no guarantee that every test will give the same result.

Comment: @HelpingHand is that tool harmless?

Comment: Yeah.  I would ensure, all work is saved before hitting the bugcheck button.  Maybe even run Sync (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sync) if you want to be paranoid to avoid any chance of unflushed data being lost  but I've used it many times.